# Drop only certain objects

Tags: class, object, stata

Consider the following toy class in Stata:

```
class numbers {
    double one = 0
    double two = 0
    double three = 0
}
```

I can create a new instance as follows:

```
.foo = .numbers.new

classutil describe .foo

numbers .foo:
        double       .one           = 0
        double       .two           = 0
        double       .three         = 0
```

I can then drop `.foo` using the `classutil` command:

```
classutil drop .foo
```

However, if i try to just drop `.foo.two`, this is not possible:

```
classutil drop .foo.two
foo.two:  can only drop top-level objects
r(459);
```

How can I drop a specific object that is not a top-level object?